# Optimizing size (font AND width) of tables produced with dcolumn/siunitx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, fontsize, siunitx, dcolumn

I have a couple of tables in my document, and it's time to finalize them. This means I want to optimize:

1) the size of the font (if possible obtain `\normalsize` as in the rest of the document, or at least the largest size possible to fit the table within the space); and

2) the distance between columns (if possible it should be equal)

Note that I have to follow these settings (thesis guidline): `geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}`

As an aside, I'd like the table captions not too big. I wonder if my size is normal here.

For the solution, I'd appreciate if I can follow it, so I can apply it to all my tables. This means I need to understand the steps undertaken to optimize each of those.

Here is the MWE in terms of dcolumn. I have tried to add only parts of my preamble which I think are important for this task.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,
format=plain,indention=2cm]{caption}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{Y}{D..{-1}}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\onehalfspacing
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption...} 
\label{a1}
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lYYYYYYYYYYYY}
\toprule 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{X1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{X2} \\
  \cmidrule(rl){2-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-5}\cmidrule(rl){6-7} \cmidrule(rl){8-9}   \cmidrule(rl){10-11} 
  \cmidrule(rl){12-13} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} 
  \\
  \midrule C1 & 0.37 & 0.37 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.44 & 0.50 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 &  0.47 & 0.26 \\ 
  C2 & 0.37 & 0.31 & 0.43 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.48 & 0.50 & 0.72 & 0.75 & 0.45 &   0.38 \\ 
  C3 & 0.37 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.12 & 0.15 & 0.37 & 0.41 & 0.46 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.43 \\ 
  C4 & 0.37 & 0.20 & 0.25 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.18 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.38 & 0.44 & 0.45 & 0.38 \\ 
  Clongnamehere5 & 0.37 & 0.32 & 0.45 & 0.12 & 0.45 & 0.50 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.57 & 0.59 & 0.45 & 0.51 \\ 
  \bottomrule\end{tabular}
  % cut here but goes on much further
 }
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

I have just noticed, that `siunitx` seems to do the job, **BUT ONLY under scriptsize**. Is this the better for the purpose?

MWE with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,
format=plain,indention=2cm]{caption}
\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\onehalfspacing
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption...} 
\label{ovb1}
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{l
S[table-format=1.2]
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2]
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2]
S[table-format=1.2]
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2] 
S[table-format=1.2] }
\toprule 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{X1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{X2} \\
  \cmidrule(rl){2-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-5}\cmidrule(rl){6-7} \cmidrule(rl){8-9}   \cmidrule(rl){10-11} 
  \cmidrule(rl){12-13} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} 
  \\
  \midrule C1 & 0.37 & 0.37 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.44 & 0.50 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 &  0.47 & 0.26 \\ 
  C2 & 0.37 & 0.31 & 0.43 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.48 & 0.50 & 0.72 & 0.75 & 0.45 & 0.38 \\ 
  C3 & 0.37 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.12 & 0.15 & 0.37 & 0.41 & 0.46 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.43 \\ 
  C4 & 0.37 & 0.20 & 0.25 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.18 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.38 & 0.44 & 0.45 & 0.38 \\ 
  Clongnamehere5 & 0.37 & 0.32 & 0.45 & 0.12 & 0.45 & 0.50 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.57 & 0.59 & 0.45 & 0.51 \\ 
  % cut here but goes on much further
  \bottomrule\end{tabular}
  }
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with the `dcolumn` package, there are two important optimizations you could make which, jointly, would let you use a fontsize directive of `\small` rather than `\scriptsize` and still make the table fit into the available text block:

- Define your decimal column layout via `\newcolumntype{Y}{D{.}{.}{1.2}}` rather than the generic `\newcolumntype{Y}{D{.}{.}{-1}`; and
- use a smaller value of `\tabcolsep`, the parameter that controls (half) the width of the intercolumn whitespace. In the example below I use a value of `3.5pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, 
   smallheadings]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,
   singlelinecheck=false,format=plain,indention=2cm]{caption}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{Y}{D..{1.2}}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\onehalfspacing
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,vmargin=2cm}
\pagestyle{headings}
% two shortcut commands
\newcommand\mcii[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mci[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\centering
\caption{Caption...} 
\label{a1}
{\small
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{Y} @{}}
\toprule 
& \mcii{X1} & \mcii{X2} & \mcii{X1}  & 
  \mcii{X1} & \mcii{X2} & \mcii{X2} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-3} \cmidrule(rl){4-5}   \cmidrule(rl){6-7} \cmidrule(rl){8-9} \cmidrule(rl){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13} 
  & \mci{A} & \mci{B} & \mci{A} & \mci{B} & 
    \mci{A} & \mci{G} & \mci{B} & \mci{A} & 
    \mci{B} & \mci{G} & \mci{A} & \mci{B} \\
\midrule 
  C1 & 0.37 & 0.37 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.44 & 0.50 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 &  0.47 & 0.26 \\ 
  C2 & 0.37 & 0.31 & 0.43 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.48 & 0.50 & 0.72 & 0.75 & 0.45 &   0.38 \\ 
  C3 & 0.37 & 0.29 & 0.29 & 0.12 & 0.15 & 0.37 & 0.41 & 0.46 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.43 \\ 
  C4 & 0.37 & 0.20 & 0.25 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.18 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.38 & 0.44 & 0.45 & 0.38 \\ 
  Clongnamehere5 & 0.37 & 0.32 & 0.45 & 0.12 & 0.45 & 0.50 & 0.45 & 0.45 & 0.57 & 0.59 & 0.45 & 0.51 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
% cut here but goes on much further
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

If you wanted to use the `siunitx` package instead of the `dcolumn` package to align the numbers on their decimal points, all you'd have to do differently is (i) load the `siunitx` package and (ii) specify the format of the `tabular` environment as

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{}}
```

instead of as

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{Y} @{}}
```

---

*Addendum*: To eliminate the guesswork related to setting the value of `\tabcolsep` so as to create a table that's as wide as `\textwidth`, you could proceed as follows; all that's assumed is that the table *will fit* if you choose `\small` as the font size.

- Set `\tabcolsep` to a value that's deliberately too small, e.g., `1pt`.
- Use a `tabular*` instead of a `tabular` environment
- Set up the layout of the `tabular*` environment as follows:

  ```
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{Y} @{}}
  ```
- Replace `\end{tabular}` with `\end{tabular*}`.

The idea is to let LaTeX calculate the extra amount of "fill" that has be inserted between the columns so as to make the `tabular*` environment take up the full allocated width (`\textwidth` in the case at hand); that's what the directive `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` accomplishes. Because `\fill` can take on only positive values, it's important to set `\tabcolsep` to something deliberately small, say, `1pt`.

By the way, if this method doesn't work for a given table, it means that `\small` generates a font that's too large; re-try with `\footnotesize`.

Comment: ok I see. I produce my tables via xtable in R if that plays a role. Which of the two packages would you recommend to me?
Did I get this right, in terms of dcolumn, I would have to set `\tabcolsep` to the right value each time via testing. In terms of siunitx, the optimization of the width is always done automatically? So siunitx would be better for me, or not? (By the way what does `@{}` do?)

Also what about the table caption. Can I reduce it just for one table to save space and would you recommend that? Or mabye generally reduce it a bit for all tables?

Thanks already, very helpful.

Comment: @TomM: The `@{}` directives eliminate the whitespace to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column. If all you needed the `siunitx` package for is for its column type `S`, I'd say there really is no difference in the resulting output. (`siunitx` does not "optimize" the width o the overall table.) Not knowing what the captions of your tables look like, I'm afraid I don't know how to answer that question. I'll provide an addendum to explain how to take out some of the guesswork relating to setting `\tabcolsep`.

Comment: yeah I just noticed the distance between columns under the siunitx table is only correct under the scriptsize-setting. If I increased that setting to e.g. small, siunitx produces a table width longer than the available margins to use.

Comment: Thanks for the Addendum, also very helpful to proceed, even if it's a lot of work to do that for each single table that I have - it's better than nothing :)

Comment: I just tried to use the above code. It throws the error:
`Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\fill): c' used ...\textwidth}{l@\extracolsep{\fill}*{12}{Y}}`
I am using `tabular*`. What am I doing wrong? I was just using the above code you provided, and changed the respective lines.

Comment: @TomM - Sorry, I had left off a curly brace, "`{`". :-( It should read `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`, not `@\extracolsep{\fill}}`. My apologies for this oversight. I've edited my answer to supply the missing curly brace.

Comment: no problem, that's what I thought. Tried to find it myself, but couldnt ;)
Have a nice evening!