# Macro to apply tabcolsep to a table from external file

Tags: tables, macros, formatting, r

I am using R to produce my tables via xtable, but I am not using Sweave to write my document. Instead I am using TexStudio and if possible would like to stick with it.

Therefore I am using `\input` to import my tables. Ideally, I would like to have all tables be as wide as `\textwidth`. It seems like there is no way in xtable yet to apply modify `\tabcolsep` directly within the function. Thus it has to be done in Latex, which means I have to do it manually for every single table.

The idea was to create a macro, which applies `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{VALUE}` at the right position within the `table` environment.

Here is a MWE table in the format of all my tables produced by R (imagine this as an external .tex file)

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption[a]{bbb} 
\label{x}
{\normalsize
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Delta} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Gamma} & \multicolumn{1} {c}{Omega} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Theta} \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$a+x$} & 0.1231 & 0.1122  & 7124 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$a+x$} & 0.3333 & 0.1122 & 7343 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$a-x$} & 0.3333 & 0.1231 & 9344 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$a-x$} & 0.2222 & 0.1231 & 9342 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

So I believe the command  `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{VALUE}` would have to be included after \normalsize. Again, the objective is to create a `tabular` with width `\textwidth`.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to clarify the reason for modifying `\tabcolsep`: The need to create a `tabular` that's as wide as `\textwidth`.

Comment: `\tabcolsep` is a  length command, so you would need `\setlength\tabcolsep{VALUE}`. If each file has only one table, you could just start a group, set this length, input the file, then close the group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\tabcolsep` is a length not a macro so it should be set using

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
```

Not `\renewcommand`.

You can set it anywhere before the table, if you set it in the document preamble it will apply to all tables in the document.

If you want to affect just one table that you are inputting then you can do

```
{\setlength\tabcolsep{15pt}\input{tablefile}}
```

However I just noticed

> Again, the objective is to create a tabular with width `\textwidth`.

Setting `\tabcolsep` is a tricky way to affect the table size using `tabular`, if you want to affect the total table width you really need an environment that takes a width argument
such as `tabular*`.  You would then need to adjust `\extracolsep` rather than `\tabcolsep`.

---

In order to specify a total table width you do not want `\begin{tabular}` you want

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolumnsep{\fill}....
```

The xtable manual suggests xtable has `width` argument to specify `\textwidth` and `tabular.environment` argument where you can specify `tabular*` instead of `tabular`.

Comment: I've just finished editing the OP's text to clarify the objective: to create a `tabular` that's automatically as wide as `\textwidth`, but without going the route of creating a `tabular*` environment with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` instructions...

Comment: @Mico Yes your comment overlapped my answer edit. I'll leave the answer as is though as it asks the question asked, even if it probably isn't what is required for the actual problem.

Comment: Ah, I may be to blame for the OP's use of `\renewcommand` in lieu of `\setlength`! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148845/5001 and my answer... I don't how long I've been doing it this way -- for some reason it works, at least for the ways I use it.

Comment: @Mico I added some info on using tabular* instead of tabular from R.

Comment: Thanks guys and again I have learned something. The above solution also helps me if I know the right value for tabcolsep by applying some manual tests. I doubt it's possible to create something like `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}
{@{\extracolumnsep{\fill}....` in R via xtable so that would be another thing I had to do manually. I wanna add one thing: `{\inputencoding{latin1}{\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}\input{filename}}` works if any inputenc errors pop up (also shown by David Carlisle in another thread)

Comment: @TomM the xtable manual explictly says you can generate `tabular*` and specify the width. width is described as: If not
NULL , the specified value is included in parenthesis between the tabular environment begin tag and the alignment specification. This allows specification of the table width when using tabular environments such as tabular* and
tabularx. Note that table width specification is not supported with the tabular or longtable environments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 1 more thing which was not shown in the question: I am using your package `dcolumn` to adjust the numbers to the decimal point. Does that work together with `tabular*`?

Comment: @TomM yes, should work

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mico for your May 2017 updates in your answer to [Optimizing size (font AND width) of tables.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148845/5001)

I was also unable to find a way to integrate `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` in the `xtable` function, unless I added it in the intermediary tex file inside the {lrrrrrrr} alignment brackets.

In the hope to save some time to the beginner-to-intermediary `xtable` user (which I am), I just found that `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{VALUE pt}` can be specified in the `size` argument of `xtable`, as shown in the [xtable Gallery vignette by Jonathan Swinton under "5.7 Table Level Commands".](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) I found out after I searched for the `tablecolsep` argument instead of `width` theme. "Table Level Commands" is not very explicit about actions like fitting the table to page width. The dedicated section "5.13 Table Width" did not specify how to expand columns automatically so they fit the whole page width.  In my case, only the last one was expanded (i.e. lines were expanded until aligned to textwidth, with no option to tell xtable to divide that expansion between columns (I may be mistaken about that).

As the table (and lines) expands automatically with longer tabcolseps when `tabular.environment = "tabular*"` and `width = "\\textwidth"` are in use, the user can fiddle with the `scalebox`argument to resize the table approximately the width of the text (visually).  `tabcolsep` can also be used in conjunction with those two. Nevertheless, this solution still requires to manually adjust `tabcolsep` for each table or document.

Comment: Update: I was still unable to integrate `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` in the `xtable`function, and was unsuccessful in defining a new column with a custom `\tabcolsep` using `@{\extracolsep{ }}` (systematically ignored and treated like `@{}` ). However, I was able to bypass the issue by inserting a `\hspace` declaration, which I believe is put the space between column width and the intercolumn separator. 
`\newcolumntype{R}{r<{\hspace{5.5pt}}}`